# Config connection string in .net core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm attempting to connect to my ASP.NET Core Web API application (.NET 6 in Visual Studio 2022 Preview) with SQL Server. And I tried to use the following code to configure the connection string in the `Startup` class as I used to.

```
services.AddDbContext<DEMOWTSSPortalContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

But in .NET 6, I recognize that `Startup` and `Program` classes are merged into one class. And the above code is not usable in .NET 6. `AddDbContext` is not recognized. So do you have any idea or documentation about this update, and how to configure connection strings in .NET 6?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

*.Net 6* Simplifies a lot of a tasks and introduces `WebApplicationBuilder` which in turn gives you access to the new *Configuration builder* and *Service Collection*

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

**Properties**

- `Configuration` : A collection of configuration providers for the application to compose. This is useful for adding new configuration sources and providers.
- `Environment` : Provides information about the web hosting environment an application is running.
- `Host` : An IHostBuilder for configuring host specific properties, but not building. To build after configuration, call Build().
- Logging : A collection of logging providers for the application to compose. This is useful for adding new logging providers.
- `Services` : A collection of services for the application to compose. This is useful for adding user provided or framework provided services.
- `WebHost` : An IWebHostBuilder for configuring server specific properties, but not building. To build after configuration, call Build().

To add a `DbContext` to the Di Container and configure it, there are many options however the most straightforward is

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SomeDbContext>(options =>
{
   options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
```

**Nugets packages**

- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`
- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` to use `UseSqlServer`

Answer (score 120):

Configuration.GetConnectionString(string connName) in .NET6 is under builder:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
string connString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

also AddDbContext() is under builder.Services:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<YourContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

});
```

Comment: AddDbContext is still not recognized under `builder.Services` for me. Is there a non-default DLL or using statement needed for this to use it in an ADO.NET-esque manner?

Answer (score 4):

1. Install Packages

   1. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll
   2. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll
   3. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll
2. Add Name Spaces in Controller

   1. `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;`
   2. `using System.IO;`
3. Add Code in

```
Controllervar objBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
          .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
IConfiguration conManager = objBuilder.Build();
var my = conManager.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

4. In appsettings.json Add Code:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-WebApplica71d622;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
},
```

Answer (score 2):

**First, You Should Install Following Nugets Package**

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
3. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

**Second, You Should update the Following Code in DbContext Class Constructor**

```
public NameOftheDBContextClass(DbContextOptions<NameOftheDBContextClass> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
```

**Third, You Should Add the Following Code in appsettings.json**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {"YourConnectionName": "Server=YourServerName;Database=YourDataBaseName;User Id=YourDataBaseUserID;Password=YourDataBaseUserPassword;"},
```

**Fourth, You Should Add the Following Code in Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<NameOftheDBContextClass>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnectionName")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `builder` on your configuration code like this

> `builder.Configuration`

Answer (score -1):

You can try to read in your controller like this..

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
  
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _logger = logger;
    string _configuration = configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings").GetChildren().FirstOrDefault(config => config.Key == "Title").Value;
}
```

NOTE: You can get the value based on the key provided above.

Answer (score -2):

```
    static string ConnectionStringSection()
    {
        var objBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        IConfiguration conManager = objBuilder.Build();
    
        var conn = conManager.GetConnectionString("SQLServerConnectionString");

        if (conn == null)
        {
            conn = "";
        }

        return conn.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. You can benefit from the guide how to answer questions [answer]

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?